# Which variable type can hold numbers as big as 10^18

Tags: c

On my computer,

```
int                     : 4 byte
long int                : 4 byte
long long int           : 8 byte
long double             : 12 byte
unsigned long double    : 12 byte
float                   : 4 byte
```

Which variable type should I use to keep numbers as big as 10^18?

Comment: You should probably specify if you mean integer or floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a precise representation, you can use `long long`. It holds at most 2^63-1 on your box, which is >10^18.

Any of the `float` types would also work, but the representation will be approximate.

Comment: thanks, it was what I firstly did. But I get wrong numbers when I trying to parse a string with the content `81834165 9999991 1 9999991 9999989 389999650 169999844 799999121 149999837`

Comment: What I did to read was: `sscanf(line, "%lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld", &N, &P1, &W1, &M, &K, &A, &B, &C, &D);`

Comment: @mustafa: works perfectly fine here. You might want to open a new question for your issue.

Comment: `long long` will certainly work on the platform in the example, but I think the goal is to find the minimum that will work on any platform.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to do arithmatic without limitations use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)

Answer (score 0):

To hold 10^18 as an integer, you need an integer type that's 64 bits wide.  It's because `int`, `long int`, et. al. vary in size across platforms that certain libraries provide types guaranteed to be of a certain size.  For example, in the gnu C library:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t myint;
```

or in the glib library from gnome: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/

```
#include <glib.h>

guint64 myint;
```